# How to retrieve all the user details from database in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am able to retrieve data from Firebase but for single user only from database in android.

I just want to get the data from database of all the with all the columns which user have entered in firebase without user authentication login.

```
 import android.os.Bundle;

 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
 import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
 import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
 import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
 import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class ViewDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {
     private static final String TAG = "ViewDatabase";

     private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
     private  String userID;

     private ListView mListView;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_database_layout);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            showData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

  }

  private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        userinfo  user = dataSnapshot.getValue(userinfo.class);

        Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + user.getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Mobile: " + user.getMob());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Vehicle: " + user.getVehicle());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Address: " + user.getaddress());

        ArrayList<String> array  = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add(user.getName());
        array.add(user.getMob());
        array.add(user.getVehicle());
        array.add(user.getaddress());
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new 
        ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here is my userinfo class:

```
public class userinfo {
   public String name;
   public String mob;
   public String vehicle;
   public String address;

   public userinfo(){
}

public userinfo(String name, String mob, String vehicle, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mob = mob;
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
    this.address = address;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getMob() {
    return mob;
}

public String getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}

public String getaddress() {
    return address;
}

}
```

Here is my database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Yb5.png)

i am just getting WjGb6At3hRdvOBBFysv65XG37k53 user in list view

Comment: mAuth.signInAnonymously()? or you can change Database rules.

Comment: What's the problem you have when you run this code? Doesn't it run? Does it run, but then does something different from what you expected? Is there any relevant message in your logcat?

Comment: as there are two user uid in my database and both are having fields with some details ,but when i am trying to retrieve both the user uid details only a single user data is retrieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. By user data, if you mean the `user` object of the other users, then simply put, you **can not** obtain the `user` object of the other users regardless of their sign-in method. You can only obtain your own `user` object by the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` method.

Having said that, if the data of the users is stored in the realtime database, you can obtain it in the same way that you obtain data from other nodes. Please note, though, that the privacy settings of your app will determine if you can read other users' data or not.

It would help if you show your database structure in the question.

**Edit After Viewing Database Structure :-**

Alright, from what I understand, this is quite a basic problem. What you need is a `childEventListener` to retrieve all the children ( in your case - users ) of the `trace-5fa8c` node.

The code for that is as follows :-

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("trace-5fa8c");

databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            userinfo  user = dataSnapshot.getValue(userinfo.class);

            Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + user.getName());
            Log.d(TAG, "showData: Mobile: " + user.getMob());
            Log.d(TAG, "showData: Vehicle: " + user.getVehicle());
            Log.d(TAG, "showData: Address: " + user.getaddress());

            //Do whatever further processing you need
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

Also, even though this is not a part of your question, I'd like to add that with each `onChildAdded(datasnapshot)`, you can get a `userInfo` pojo. So, in your `showData()` method, instead of creating a new `Arraylist` each time, maintain a single `Arraylist<UserInfo>` and keep adding the child pojo to it each time a child is added. This `ArrayList` object will be the dataset for your `ListView` object.

Comment: sir i have attached a link of my database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060629/i-have-inserted-location-using-geofire-in-firebase