# How can I check Geofire to log user out if no Geofire was created?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

**Summary of problem:** I am new to Android Studio and Firebase with Geofire, please be gentle.  My goal is to log the user out when they are on the map screen of my app without a Geofire location.  I cannot figure out how to query "g" in my Geofire.  How do I query the "g" child to see if it was created or not?  And if "g" was not created, they need to be logged out.  So the goal is query for "g" and create method that if "g" is null, logs user out.

**Things I have done:** Many Stackoverflow posts were not using Android Studio.  I did find this [I have inserted location using geofire in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060629/i-have-inserted-location-using-geofire-in-firebase) but it did not resolve my issue.  I also tried [Google firebase check if child exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397205/google-firebase-check-if-child-exists)

**onLocationChanges is where I add the Online Vendor and where I want to also check to see if "g" was created or not.**

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    // Adds VendorOnline Child to Firebase when Vendor is On This Activity
    addVendorOnline();
    // Log user out if they are on the map screen without a "VendorOnline" Uid
    logVendorOutIfBuggy();

}
```

**This is the method to create the Online Vendor and check if "g" was created:**

```
 private void addVendorOnline(){

    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {

        String vendorId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference vendorIdReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("VendorOnline");
        GeoFire vendorGeoFire = new GeoFire(vendorIdReference);
        vendorGeoFire.setLocation(vendorId, new GeoLocation(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
    }  


   // Log user out if for some reason they do not have a "g" child but are on the map screen.
   private void logVendorOutIfBuggy() {
   DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("g");

    if(ref == null){

        Toast.makeText(VendorMapsActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    }
```

**What I expect to happen and what actually happens:**  I expect the user to be logged out if "g" is equals null, but right now the user does not get logged out.

[image: how to query for g]

Comment: The `g` property is automatically created/updated by Geofire when you write a location to a key. You should not have to do anything specifically for that property, as long as you're using Geofire. It sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What are you trying to accomplish by detecting the `g` creation?

Comment: I am trying to log the user out if no "g" was detected.

Comment: I would call `getLocation` for the vendor key and the `LocationCallback` should return a null value in `onLocationCallback` if a location had never been set (or removed).  Also it would be inconsistent if there were 'l' values and no 'g' so it is fair to deduce no 'g' on no location.

Comment: Awesome this sounds promising.  Would you be able to give an example code?  Thanks friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of calling `getLocation` to see if vendor registered a location.

From javadocs of `LocationCallback.onLocationResult` :

> This method is called with the current location of the key. location
>   will be null if there is no location stored in GeoFire for the key.

```
        final String vendorKey = "someVendorKey";
        geoFire.getLocation(vendorKey, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                if (key.compareTo(vendorKey) == 0) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        // vendor has not logged a location yet (or it was removed)
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Awesome!  This looks like what I was exactly looking for.  No other solution I have found in other posts look anything like this.  Just to clarify, I leave the vendorKey as "someVendorKey" right?

Comment: No it would be the uid key for the vendor which you have as an image (otherwise I would have copied it).

Comment: Ah okay I see.  The uid key changes to a random key for every user that logs in.  I use anonymous logging in.  Is there a way to account for that when getting the vendorKey?

Comment: You're the best.  Your help is what exactly I needed.  Thank you.  I got it to work.  `if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {

        final String user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference vendorIdReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("VendorOnline");
        GeoFire vendorGeoFire = new GeoFire(vendorIdReference); ...` combined with the LocationCallBack, it now works if a VendorOnline is not created!